# Camunda 7 JUnit Test Mocking Service in Expression on Listenr

Tags: java, junit4, camunda

Hi I am trying to do simple unit test (junit 4) to test process workflow without spring boot beans. Just plain JUnit test with ProcessEngineRule.

Mocking java delegates worked with autoMock() from CamundaMockito, but I have problem with mocking services which are used directly in Expressions in model.

This is example:

[image]

I am getting error  `org.camunda.bpm.engine.context ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: Unknown property used in expression: ${myService.setPath(x)}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'myService'`

Here is how my test look like:

```
@Deployment(resources = { "test.bpmn" })
public class SimpleTest {
    @ClassRule
    @Rule
    public static ProcessEngineRule rule = TestCoverageProcessEngineRuleBuilder.create().build();

    @Mock
    MyService myService;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        init(rule.getProcessEngine());
        Mocks.register("myService", myService);
    }

    @Test

    public void testHappyPath() {
        autoMock("test.bpmn");

        final ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService()
            .startProcessInstanceByKey("test");
      ...
    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I would appreciate some help or directions.